# ExpanderViewer selectionchanged or selectedItem (Windows Phone)

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I'm trying to use ExpanderViewer with Binding, I followed this [tutorial](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-Toolkit-ExpanderView-in-depth-Part2-Data-Binding)

now I need an event that fires on taping on one of the ExpanderViewer Items. is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using this: `<Controls:ExpanderView Expanded="ExpanderView_Expanded" />`

And for every item separately you have to add the events in the datatemplate, for example:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="CustomHeaderTemplate">
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiLight}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Comment: I want an event to fire when you tap on one of the expanded items. these items show when you expand the main one.

Comment: There, I expanded my answer... is that what you mean?

Comment: But with this event handler, how can I get the binded Object of the selected Item?

Comment: In the event handler: var someTempVariable = sender as YourViewModel;

Comment: that will return the control itself. I used the DataContext to get the data. Thanks for your help :)